# I am getting Unhandled Promise Rejection error even though I have the catch section in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am just trying to handle the data from the post request. I am handling data in the catch section so as to log it in the console, but still, I am getting the error Unhandled Promise Rejection.

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    });
    product
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Handling post request to /products.',
        createdProduct: product
    });
});
```

Comment: And whats the error inside the unhandled rejection? It's most likely not caused by the code shown

Comment: The code in the question won't compile, it has an extra `;` in a critical location and the "enter code here" placeholder. Please don't *retype* code when asking for help. Use **copy and paste**. Please also take the time to review your question before clicking the Post Your Question button, to ensure that it's correct and accurate. Re the question: If we assume the `;` is a typo that isn't in your actual code, then the code shown will not cause an unhandled rejection error, which would mean the problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the db libraries do that. I had similar experience before. You can use global error handler and see what is going on.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p){
   //call handler here
});
```

this might shed some more light to the issue.

Comment: What libraries do that which support/return promises and are handled? `Mongoose` would not.

Comment: i had exp with postgres. Anyway getting the exact error will rule out any guess work.

Comment: Yes, I am using Mongoose. I am new to Node actually.

Comment: @AdityaSinha try to get the exact error and see what's going on.